# Idiom or quote that means "Decided to be the opposite of [a person]"

Tags: idioms

I'm looking for an idiom (or pithy quote) that is equivalent to saying;

*Having met that person, I decided that I would absolutely do the opposite of what they would do.*

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Superman to the rescue again:

> Having met John, I decided to be [Bizarro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bizarro_Jerry) John

Bizzaro is a DC comic character whose powers are the exact opposite of Superman's.

Also see: [The Bizarro Jerry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bizarro_Jerry), a Seinfeld episode where they meet a polar opposite of Jerry.

The word has decent permeation in pop culture. If your audience is familiar with Superman and/or Seinfeld, you should have no trouble getting your meaning across.

[Wikipedia]

EDIT: Thanks to ScotM for the [Urban Dictionary link](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bizarro)

Comment: +1 [The Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bizarro) supports your choice :-)

Answer (score 1):

... I decided to be the **anti-**{person's name}.